# SharePoint list.items.GetDataTable column names not match field names

Tags: sharepoint, datatable, dataview

I am binding an SPGridView to a SPList. As code samples suggest, I am using the following code to create a dataview based on the list.

```
dim data as DataView = myList.Items.GetDataTable.DefaultView
grid.DataSource = data
etc...
```

What I am finding is that the column names in the resulting dataview do not always match the source fields defined in the SPList. For example I have columns named

- Description
- ReportItem
- ReportStatus

  these show up in the resulting dataview with column names like
- ReportType0
- ReportStatus1

This leads me to think that I have duplicate field names defined, but that does not seem to be the case.

Seems like I am missing something fundamental here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetDataTable` method is returning the `internalName` (or `staticName` -- I can't remember for sure which but they are frequently the same) representation of the columns, rather than the `Title` representation, which is what you see in the Web interface. I believe `GetDataTable` does a CAML query under the covers, and you have to use that `internalName` for field references in CAML.

This [blog](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/03/12/wss-columns-specify-internal-name.aspx) talks about it in a little more detail.

Answer (score 4):

So I posted about this on my blog, but I wrote a little utility method that you can use, right after you get the data table it basically remaps the column names in the DataTable to their friendly names.

```
DataTable table = list.GetItems(list.DefaultView).GetDataTable();
foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
   column.ColumnName = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(column.ColumnName).Title;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you also could do (if you´re using .NET 3.5) is to use an anonymous type and bind against that. If you´re doing this you might wanna go with a Linq DataSource as well.
I have made a post that explains this [here](http://johanleino.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6BE273C70C45B5D1!328.entry).